# Crank set removal tool too small

Tags: crankset

My crank set removal tool is too small to screw into the arm. You can see the black space in-between the tool and the crank.

Where can I buy the proper sized tool? Seems like all crank set removal tools come in the same size with regards to the threaded component that screws into the base of the arm.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a [Stronglight or TA crank puller](http://store.velo-orange.com/index.php/ja-stein-crank-puller-for-classic-stronglight-or-ta-cranks.html).

To identify which one you need, you'll have to either figure out the manufacturer of the crank or measure the ID of the thread with a caliper (a basic one is under $20 and useful for all sorts of stuff), making the correct allowance for the fact that you're measuring an internal thread. (In other words, that 23 or 23.5 number is going to be the OD of the external thread. The internal threads are a smaller number, i.e. the nominal thread size minus twice the thread height, and the thread height is *probably* around .5-.6mm, but I don't know that for sure because these are weirdo threads that aren't on [standard dimension charts](http://www.newmantools.com/tech/threadmf.htm).)

Comment: Park used to make a crank puller that had a "reversible" threaded section for this case.

Comment: How do I know if I need the 23 mm or 23.35 mm?

Comment: With a ruler @the_prole ?

Comment: Found the "threading measurement" for my model [here](http://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=201ac3da-4c28-4b72-903e-623584e07d7b&Enum=115) just by typing my crank model (written on the crank) into Google